# Router Link to a new Page but keep Store data

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a list of posts which on click navigate to the post view where you can read it. For the sake of User Experience i want it to open a new Tab on click of the post.

I achieve this with `<nuxt-link :to="'posts/' + posts[0].docID" target="_blank">`

My current website logic works with fetching the data of the posts from my Database into the store so that i dont have to fetch the post data again on post load.
This works fine, but with my new logic of opening a new Tab the post Component doesnt find store data and so it fetches the database again.

How can i achieve a new tab behaviour without resetting the store and keeping the post data ready without a need to refetch?

Comment: You would have to use some sort of local storage option, e.g. `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` or IndexedDB

Comment: Potentially you could also use a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#cache_and_return_requests) to catch that URL and serve a cached version after the first request. Or have your API set an appropriate cache so the browser naturally doesn't hit the URL twice (assuming the DB fetch is a parameterized GET)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cookie or Local storage for this where you can save your data and re-fetch in new tab...

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open('/posts/' + posts[0].docID)